# Split a CSV line with an specific pattern with JAVA

Tags: java

I am reading a CSV file with Java. I am storing each value between commas into a String Array.

**This is what prints when I read a CSV line:**

Tania, Joe, Pat, , , , , , ,

When I store this line into a String Array:
String [] myString = line.split(",");

I get this output when I print my string:
[Tania, Joe, Pat]

And I want to get:
[Tania, Joe, Pat, , , , , , ,]

I want to store the empty spaces as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have checked Stackoverflow site, use `line.split(",",-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a limit to get a specific number of entries

```
line.split("<regex>",<limit>)
```

from here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)